# Pinterest api works for users who log in via emai, but not for those logging in via facebook

Tags: oauth, pinterest

I'm using Dirk Groenen's Pinterest-API-PHP code (https://github.com/dirkgroenen/Pinterest-API-PHP/) for a site, and I'm having an interesting problem.

When I link (grant permission and exchange auth code for long-lived token) a user that logs in via email address, I have no problems. I can pull their profile data and post on their behalf.

When I link a user that logs in via facebook (Pinterest's login screen offers various options), I can grant access, but I get an http 401 on trying to get user details.

My google-fu must be weak, I can't find anything that resembles this issue (or it's lost in all the noise of the search results.)

Anyone have an idea?